# Find tapped icon using X and Y coordinates

Tags: android, coordinates, ontouchlistener, motionevent

I have file list in my android application. when the user double tap on a file I need to find out it. I could write the code to find out double tab action and X and Y coordinates of the user tap. But how can I find out the particular file or folder that the user did double tap? 
This is the code what I used:

```
private View.OnTouchListener onTouchListener=new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                long thisTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
                if(thisTime - lastTouchTime <500){

                    float x=event.getX();
                    float y=event.getY();
                    System.out.println("x :"+x);
                    System.out.println("y "+y);


                }else{
                    lastTouchTime=thisTime;

                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
```

I cannot find out it using icon sizes because they are not similar and user able to change it as they wish for icon image. Is there anyway to find out particular icon using X and Y coordinates of user tap?

Comment: post what you have attempted so far

Comment: @GauravGupta I updated the question with the code I have done so far.